# How can I only print the link with correct keywords in this code?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

Here is what I have so far, right now I just need the output to only be the link with "lion-double-ring" because right now idle prints the whole page of info. This should loop until the link is found and print the link with the given keywords. Maybe regex is the way to go here?
link

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('walmart.com)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')
links = soup.find_all('loc')
if "lion" and "double" in str(links):
print str(links)
else:
print('nothing')
```

Comment: this is the link shop.exclucitylife.com/products/lion-double-ring

Comment: Thank you, that will help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('http://shop.exclucitylife.com/sitemap_products_1.xml?from=1331122689&to=8543902145')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('loc')
for link in links:
    if 'lion-double-ring' in link.text:
        print(link.text)
        break
else:
    print('nothing')
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you checkout the edit I made above to original post? Cant finish the email part..

Comment: Sorry, I do not familiar with mail module.